# Channel api: persistent disconnections and connections

Tags: google-app-engine, go, channel-api

I am using Channel API, and after about 1 minute after channel's opening in terminal I see

```
INFO     2015-10-20 11:18:08,489 module.py:786] default: "POST /_ah/channel/disconnected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2278
2015/10/20 11:18:10 handlerMain executed
INFO     2015-10-20 11:18:10,482 module.py:786] default: "POST /_ah/channel/connected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2279
2015/10/20 11:18:13 handlerMain executed
INFO     2015-10-20 11:18:13,486 module.py:786] default: "POST /_ah/channel/disconnected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2279
2015/10/20 11:18:14 handlerMain executed
INFO     2015-10-20 11:18:14,482 module.py:786] default: "POST /_ah/channel/connected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2279
```

and so on..

my .go file

```
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handlerMain)
}
func handlerMain(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            log.Println("handlerMain executed")

            c := appengine.NewContext(r)
            tok, err := channel.Create(c, "123")
            if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
            }   
            templ := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./templates/posts.html"))
            err = templ.Execute(w, map[string]string{
                    "token": tok,
            })  
            if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
            }   
 }
```

javascript from my .html file

```
  <script>
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{.token}}');
    socket = channel.open();
    socket.onopen = onOpened;
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    socket.onerror = onError;
    socket.onclose = onClose;
  </script>
```

If it where just simple  notifications, I could have handle it, but this disconnections reexecutes my handlerMain() function, and in this function I want to start goroutine which will send messages to client, in this case I will have multiple repetitions of messages in my html page.

Any thoughts?
Is there alternative for Channel API? I know that websockets unfortunately doesn't work with GAE

UPDATE:
In browser I see GET XMLHttpRequests are sent every second to the

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/channel/dev?command=poll&channel=237c7242478266a2856d947decce4b55-channel-2105948409-1445426965-123&client=1
```

with header Connection : "keep alive";

When I switch browser to another tab, after a few seconds these requests are stopped(or very much slowed down), and I start recieve this connection/disconnection notifications. If i jump back to the page, requests are sent again every second, and no notifications.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve here (not familiar with Go) or why your main handler for "/" is called by POST requests to /_ah/channel/* routes. The disconnects typically originates from the client switching to a different page or doing a page refresh. In other words, if the page loads, the client will call /_ah/channel/connect, if the page is "closed", the client will call /_ah/channel/disconnect. Typically you would add a connect handler and a disconnect handler to your app, different from your handlerMain for "/".

Comment: @Ani, That is the case, I should recieve requests to */connect and /disconnect only ins situations which you have mentioned. In this example,  I open channel succesfully and recieve one POST  /_ah/channel/connect. So everything is fine for now. But then, after some time,(I do nothing with webpage, just stare at it) connects and disconnects start to follow each after another, as described above. It looks like Channel have some kind of timeout.

Comment: And yes, handlerMain should be executed only after page reload, so this is another problem

Comment: @Kain I have checked my logs, I don't see random disconnects and Channel API works fine for push notifications in my apps (Python) . Maybe something in your client code makes the browser send the POST disconnect request? Have you looked into your browser's developer tools / console?

Comment: @Ani please, look at the edited post. I have figured out that reconnects happens only when localhost tab in browser is inactive.

Comment: I didn't know you are running on local dev server. This might be a behavior that only happens with localhost, maybe because of security issues (same origin policy). If so, this SO question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260620/google-app-engine-channel-api-javascript-location  Try to deploy your app into test production environment and see if the behavior still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channels connection/disconnections appears only on my macbook, not on the PC. Looks like it have something to do with app-engine development server, here more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/dLe2UvzUgdA